# How to write a mysql join query using IN()

Tags: mysql, function, join

Can you help me write my MySQL join query. Here is what i have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id IN 
(table1.comma_separated_ids) WHERE table1.id = [some id]
```

where table1.comma_separated_ids is a VARCHAR column containing a list of comma separated IDs (integers) that relate to IDs in table2.

The above query returns only one row when it should return every row in table1.comma_separated_ids that has a matching row in table2

What I'm actually trying to do is a little more complex but it's hard to explain so I'm starting here. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you cannot put a comma-separated list as a *single* argument to `in`.  It is treated as a string, a single string.

You can use `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN
     table2
     ON find_in_set(table2.id, table1.comma_separated_ids)
WHERE table1.id = XXX;
```

However, the bigger issue is that you are storing ids in a comma-separated list.  These should be in a separate junction table, with one row per id.  It is bad enough to store lists in strings; storing *integer* ids is even worse.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that when I run this query with EXPLAIN it isn't using the index on table2 to find these records. Is there no other way? Thanks again.

Comment: @PHPguru . . . Of course not.  You need to structure the data correctly -- using a junction table -- if you want performance.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with IN() like in my original example? It seems if this would just work with IN() then it could us the index. P.S. This is someone else's database design.

Comment: @PHPguru . . . No, not in this context.  Fix the data structure if you want MySQL to use an index.

Comment: If IN() can use the index, and if PostgreSQL can use the index on such a query as this, there's no reason why MySQL couldn't make this use the index too if it wanted to.

Comment: @PHPguru . . . Postgres *and* MySQL will both use indexes for an `IN` list of constants.  Neither will use traditional indexes for matching substrings in the middle of a string (although both support full text indexes that will match words in text).  Perhaps you want a full text index.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I don't need an index in the middle of the string. What I want is for FIND_IN_SET() to use table2's primary key index just as IN() does or PostgreSQL does. PostgreSQL doesn't have a function specifically named FIND_IN_SET() but it has an equivalent function ANY() that accomplishes the same thing. ANY() would use the primary key index on table2 while searching for matches in the string of comma separated ids. However FIND_IN_SET does not use any index at all.